# Can you use JUnit to compare two String ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

For example, if you have the following two ArrayLists:

```java
ArrayList<String> arrLst1 = new ArrayList<String>();
arrLst1.add("Hello");
arrLst1.add("Goodbye");

ArrayList<String> arrLst2 = new ArrayList<String>();
arrLst2.add("Greetings");
arrLst2.add("See you soon");
```

If I wanted to use JUnit, my guess would be to use something like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.*;

public class myTest {
  @Test
  public void firstTest() {
    assertArrayEquals("Error Message", arrLst1, arrLst2);
  }
}
```

However, I'm having an issue where once I run the code, it states that the two values are equal. Looking at the documentation, I don't see anything for assertArrayEquals() for two String ArrayLists. Is this even something that is possible?

Comment: Which version of JUnit you're using?

Comment: ArrayLists are just objects. How about `assertEquals`?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri - I believe 4

Answer (score 4):

`assertArrayEquals` is for arrays, and `ArrayList<T>` is not an array.

### JUnit5

Use JUnit5 and:

```
assertIterableEquals(expected, actual); //from org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
```

[will assert](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertIterableEquals-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) that `expected` and `actual` iterables are *deeply* equal.

---

### JUnit4

If you use JUnit4, upgrade to JUnit5; however, if still with 4, then, generally, you will need to override `.equals()` method in your Generic Type Argument class (`T` in `List<T>`), after which, you can use:

```
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Note, that if your generic argument (typed contained in your list) is `String`, you do not need (you cannot, actually) override `.equals()`, since String already overrides it perfectly fine.

Comment: Note that in this case however, `expected` and `actual` aren't checked to see if their types are equal too, only if their contents are.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`assertEquals`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-), which has an overload taking two `Object` arguments, like so:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


var a = List.of("hello");
var b = List.of("hello");

assertEquals(a, b); // passes

var c = List.of("hello");
var d = List.of("world");

assertEquals(c, d); // fails
```

In this case, `assertEquals` method uses the [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) overridden method of `List` to determine if both lists contain the same contents.

Comment: Thank you for this!